# What does the random "ding" in Google Maps Navigation signify?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-maps-navigation

Ever since updating my Nexus S to ICS, I've noticed that when using Navigation I sometimes hear a random "ding" when driving around.

Any idea what this means? I was thinking maybe it was a warning about the speed limit or something, but I haven't noticed any particular circumstances whenever it does it. Sometimes its multiple times per journey, other times not at all.

In the UK, Nexus S 4.0.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you might be getting the "ding" noise discussed on [this Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/maps/google-maps-for-mobile/c4QfRlQDYj8):

> Thanks for the question. The alert chime you here indicates is a
>   prompt for an upcoming driving maneuver. It plays in places where the
>   Text-to-Speech engine is either unsupported or unavailable, but it
>   also may play if the data connection becomes flaky during guidance and
>   Navigation isn't able to process a road name in time.

Comment: Ok that kinda makes sense, the text-to-speech for Navigation has been buggy since I updated to ICS, it sometimes fluctuates between 2 different voices!

Comment: Also worth noticing from the same link: A single _ding_  appears to be a warning for an upcoming section where you have to continue straight ahead. A _ding-dong_ seems to indicate an upcoming turn.

Comment: Anyway to change the ding noise? Or set it to None? I want to keep the voice but get rid of the annoying notification ding